# Seal Self Encrypting Disk (sed) password in TPM

Tags: linux, security, encryption, ssd, tpm

I have a Self Encrypted Disk (SED). I'd like to use `sedutil` to lock the disk, but I want the password to be sealed in the `TPM` module on board the system, instead of in `ATA BIOS`.

Essentially I want the `Pre-Boot Authentication (PBA)` image to pick up the password from the `TPM` automatically upon boot.

I haven't yet been able to find a way to do this. I've found some documentation on how to lock the disk, such as this - [SED Setup](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Self-encrypting_drives), and from [Drive Trust Alliance GitHub page](https://github.com/Drive-Trust-Alliance/sedutil)  but the steps are confusing and the first link has disclaimers saying info may be outdated or is otherwise unverified. Haven't come across much literature on this otherwise.

The `SSD` manufacturer does provide a way to lock the disk using its utility, but those are not available on `Linux`, and hence I've to use `sedutil` for it...

On a Linux system, what would be the way to achieve the above, locking disk and sealing in `TPM`?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue

Comment: @dberm22 I'm interested in this as well. BTW, I've found Ubuntu Core - it is not exactly what OP is asking about, but may be worth a glance...

Comment: For everyone asking, please provide more information about your hardware. What type of disk is this? Is it Opal compliant (version 1 or 2?) or what?